# Display product variations in WooCommerce Hand-picked Products block

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

I'm attempting to show the product variations of products while using the woocommerce Hand-picked Products block.

For the shop and archive pages this solution works fine.

[How to add variation selection in Woo commerce to the Products Archive page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175053/how-to-add-variation-selection-in-woo-commerce-to-the-products-archive-page/77839867)

However I'm struggling to get the variations to show using the woocommerce blocks.

```
/**
 * Display product variations in WooCommerce Hand-picked Products block.
 *
 * @param array $attributes Block attributes.
 * @param string $content Block content.
 * @return string
 */
function custom_display_product_variations_in_handpicked_block($attributes, $content) {
    // Check if the block is a Hand-picked Products block
    if ($attributes['name'] === 'woocommerce/handpicked-products') {

        // Get the list of hand-picked product IDs
        $product_ids = ! empty($attributes['products']) ? $attributes['products'] : array();

        if (! empty($product_ids)) {
            $content .= '<ul class="product-variations-list">';

            foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
                // Get product variations
                $variations = wc_get_product_variations($product_id);

                if ($variations) {
                    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                        $variation_id = $variation->get_id();
                        $variation_name = wc_get_formatted_variation($variation->get_variation_attributes(), true);
                        $variation_price = $variation->get_price_html();

                        // Display variation details
                        $content .= '<li>';
                        $content .= '<a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink($variation_id)) . '">' . esc_html($variation_name) . '</a>';
                        $content .= '<span class="variation-price">' . $variation_price . '</span>';
                        $content .= '</li>';
                    }
                }
            }

            $content .= '</ul>';
        }
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('render_block', 'custom_display_product_variations_in_handpicked_block', 10, 2);
```